# Python one-liner to call list of functions

Tags: python, function, events, iteration

I've got some old code where I stored lists of functions in Python as class attributes. These lists are used as a sort of event hook.

To call each function in the list with appropriate arguments, I've used one-liners, mixing `map` with `lambda` expressions. I'm now concerned that there is unnecessary overhead in using `lambda` expressions like this.. I guess the recommended way would be to drop both `map` and `lambda` and just use a standard for loop, for readability.

Is there a better (read faster) one-liner to do this, though?

For example:

```
class Foo:
    """Dummy class demonstrating event hook usage."""
    pre  = [] # list of functions to call before entering loop.
    mid  = [] # list of functions to call inside loop, with value
    post = [] # list of functions to call after loop.
    def __init__(self, verbose=False, send=True):
        """Attach functions when initialising class."""
        self._results = []
        if verbose:
            self.mid.append( self._print )
        self.mid.append( self._store )
        if send:
            self.post.append( self._send )

    def __call__(self, values):

        # call each function in self.pre (no functions there)
        map( lambda fn: fn(), self.pre )

        for val in values:
            # call each function in self.mid, with one passed argument
            map( lambda fn: fn(val), self.mid )

        # call each fn in self.post, with no arguments
        map( lambda fn: fn(), self.post )

    def _print(self, value):
        """Print argument, when verbose=True."""
        print value

    def _store(self, value):
        """Store results"""
        self._results.append(value)

    def _send(self):
        """Send results somewhere"""

# create instance of Foo
foo = Foo(verbose=True)

# equivalent to: foo.__call__( ... )
foo( [1, 2, 3, 4] )
```

Is there a better way to write those one-liner `map` calls?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Apply list of functions on an object in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11736407/apply-list-of-functions-on-an-object-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recommended way is definitely to use for loops, however, if you insist on using `map`, then `operator.methodcaller` might be just what you need:

```
>>> def foo(*args):
...    print 'foo',args
... 
>>> def bar(*args):
...    print 'bar',args
... 
>>> from operator import methodcaller
>>> 
>>> map(methodcaller('__call__',1,2,3),[foo,bar])
foo (1, 2, 3)
bar (1, 2, 3)
[None, None]
```

A word of caution about using `map` for this -- It won't work if you port your code to python 3 since `map` became lazy.

You could also use list comprehensions pretty trivially (and that works on python3 also):

```
[fn() for fn in self.pre]
[fn(val) for fn in self.mid]
```

etc.

Comment: `operator.methodcaller` is a new one to me :) But I'm not sure that I'll use it, for clarity's sake. Thanks for the warning about `map` in Python3.

Answer (score 1):

First of all "I'm concerned that there is unnecessary overhead" is no way to optimise your code. Use a profiler to find the hotspots.

Secondly, your code could do with comments to let the reader know what is going on.

Finally, until proven otherwise, the following is a fine way to accomplish the task:

```
for func in self.pre: func()
#apply every function in self.mid to every value in values
for func,val in itertools.product(self.mid, values):
    func(val)
```

If you wanted to capture the values, you could use a list comprehension; if you wanted to delay evaluation, you could use a generator expression.

Comment: +1 for simplicity (and for not building unnecessary lists of return values). But I think you wanted to use `itertools.product` instead of `zip` ?

Comment: @moooeeeep I see that I do. That said, I refer OP to my second point: his code needs comments.

Comment: I've seen lambda expressions crop up in cProfile results before, sometimes fairly significantly due to the number of times called. Hence I asked. I'm sure you guys are right; for loops are blatantly the way to go!

Comment: @AlexLeach I'd bet that those lambda expressions are coming up because they are hit a lot. You can't say "I see lambda expressions come up in profiler results, therefore they are slow". It's all about the hotspots in your specific code.

Comment: @Marcin: Also, "slower than <insert some other method here>" doesn't necessarily mean *slow*.

Comment: True, true. I never said lambda expressions are slow, though.. The fact that they show up in profile results at all, seems to indicate that there is some overhead in dynamically creating them, that could otherwise be avoided. As another example, there is slight overhead in attribute lookups, which can be avoided by assigning to a local variable before entering some huge nested loop.

Comment: @AlexLeach Do you think that loops showing up in results indicates that loops suffer from overhead?

Comment: err, yes. Kind of why I started using `map`, where the for loop is moved to C-level code

Comment: @AlexLeach They show up because your thread of execution passes through there a lot. That happens because it's a loop, and the purpose is to have the thread of execution pass through the body multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> def chain(*fn):
>>>     return lambda *args, **kwargs: [_(*args, **kwargs) for _ in fn]
>>>
>>> def add(x, y):
>>>    return(x + y)
>>>
>>> def multiply(x, y):
>>>    return(x * y)
>>>
>>> chained = chain(add, multiply)
>>> chained(2, 6)

[8, 12]
```