# Apply multiple functions to the same argument in functional Python

Tags: python, dictionary, functional-programming

I am trying to "invert" `map` (same function, multiple arguments) in a case where I have multiple function that I want to apply to the same argument. I am trying to find a more function approach to replace the classical

```
arg = "My fixed argument"
list_of_functions = [f, g, h] #note that they all have the same signature
[fun(arg) for fun in list_of_functions]
```

The only thing I could come up with is

```
map(lambda x: x(arg), list_of_functions)
```

which is not really great.

Comment: Make sure you tell the Haskell people that list comprehensions aren't functional...

Comment: Bad phrasing. I really don't want to start a war with the Haskell people :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Apply list of functions on an object in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11736407/apply-list-of-functions-on-an-object-in-python)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try:

```
from operator import methodcaller

map(methodcaller('__call__', arg), list_of_functions)
```

The [`operator`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html) module also has similar functions for getting fixed attributes or items out of an object, often useful in functional-esque programming style. Nothing directly for calling a callable, but [`methodcaller`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.methodcaller) is close enough.

Though, I personally like list comprehension more in this case. Maybe if there was a direct equivalent in the `operator` module, like:

```
def functioncaller(*args, **kwargs):
    return lambda fun:fun(*args, **kwargs)
```

…to use it as:

```
map(functioncaller(arg), list_of_functions)
```

…then maybe it would be convenient enough?

Comment: Not sure if I agree. Isn't this creating `(f.arg(), g.arg(), h.arg())`?

Comment: @meto: ah, sorry, you found my post before I realized my mistake. It's fixed now ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the correction. I agree that this looks uglier than the list comprehensions. I would really like to see a `functioncaller` function, even if I understand that the usage would be quite limited

Answer (score 1):

In Python 3 your `map()` example returns a map object, so the functions are only called when it is iterated over, which is at least lazy.

Comment: Of course, the same holds for the generator expression `(fun(arg) for fun in list_of_functions)`.

Comment: Thanks for the note, but my question is more about the syntax. For now I don't really care if i get back a generator or an actual object

Comment: I'd go with the generator expression in JAB's comment if you are using a new enough version of Python.