# Mapping multiple functions to a single value

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working on some python exercises. I understand there are more efficient ways of solving this problem, however, I am trying to get a better understanding of what the question is asking.

Q: Use a `map` and `lambda` to pass multiple functions to a single value.

It is important to note here that I have not assigned a variable name as `list`.
Here is what I have tried:

```
import math

mult_funcs = [math.sqrt, math.log]

test_func = list(map(lambda x: x, mult_funcs))
test_func(2)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-89-6561142477ba> in <module>
      1 test_func = list(map(lambda x: x, func_lst))
----> 2 test_func(2)

TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

Investigating SO led me to this solution: [Apply multiple functions to the same argument in functional Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33659139/apply-multiple-functions-to-the-same-argument-in-functional-python)

Now, I have the code below which works. However, I am curious how to modify the `lambda` function so the value can change from 2 to any other number. In other words, I'd like to be able to do a regular function call (e.g., `test_func(4)`) instead of setting the lambda equal to a variable.

```
arg = 2
test_func = list(map(lambda x: x(arg), mult_funcs))
```

Comment: In the first variant you create a list (what the `list(...)` call does) and assign it to `test_func`. In the next line you try to call this list. In the second variant you can just replace the `arg` in the second line by `4` or anything else. First line can then be omitted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to call `test_func` it needs to be a function. So if you need to start with:

```
test_func = lambda x: ...
```

With that you can use `map` within that function and that `map` will need another lambda. Something like:

```
import math

mult_funcs = [math.sqrt, math.log]

test_func = lambda x: list(map(lambda f: f(x), mult_funcs))
test_func(2)
# [1.4142135623730951, 0.6931471805599453]
```

Which will capture the passed in number in a closure and apply the functions to it in the second lambda.

Comment: Hmm, why use `lambda` for `test_func` rather than `def`?

Comment: @HeapOverflow Because that’s the assignment. But I agree, a `def` makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Your first code snippet did not work because `test_func` at the end of `lambda` operation is a list and you can't do a function-call like thing on your list.

The most pythonic way would be to iterate over than using `lambda`:

```
import math

mult_funcs = [math.sqrt, math.log]

arg = 2
test_func = [x(arg) for x in mult_funcs]
# or: test_func = list(map(lambda x: x(arg), mult_funcs))

print(test_func)
```

In fact, the variable `test_func` is not a function here, but you get the idea.

Comment: That makes sense and I appreciate the alternative approach to solving this problem. In the spirit of the exercise question I was required to use map and lambda.