# How to apply sequence of functions to an object?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, scope

Based on a set of instructions in the form of a `string`, I have to apply certain instructions (fxns) on an object, one after the other. This is a part of a larger system. I've arrived at this point. I need a way to iterate, and return the object's condition at the end of the instructions. I came across [this reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11736407/apply-list-of-functions-on-an-object-in-python), but over there, functions are being applied to a constant initial data to get a list of outputs. In my case however, the object is changing with the iteration. hence the `while` statement, but I also need an `iterate` to apply my `ith` function.

I tried to make a recursive function as well (it was inside a for statement, and it didn't feel right at all), with the base condition being length of instructions reaching 0, (each recursive call carrying out an instruction, till no more left, hence it is also decreasing in complexity), it looks like a good candidate for recursion, and I will appreciate a solution in that manner, if anyone is interested.

```
instruction_dict = {'D': lambda x : x/2 , 'M': lambda x: x%2, 'P':lambda x: x*2 , 'S': lambda x : x-2, 'A': lambda x : x+2}
instruction_set = 'PPPPPDDSAM'

def mycomputation (num):
    count, intermediate = 0, num
    fun_args = [instruction_dict[i] for i in instruction_set]

    while count <= len(fun_args):
        intermediate, count = fun_args(intermediate), count +1 #list is not callable, actually need fun_args[i](intermediate)
    return intermediate
```

fun_args is a list and a list is not callable, actually need something like - `fun_args[i](intermediate)`

Comment: @khelwood apologies. Should be fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is quite simple:

```
def mycomputation(num):
    for instruction in instruction_set:
        num = instruction_dict[instruction](num)
    return num
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list of functions, you can then apply them one by one:

```
for fun in fun_args:
    intermediate = fun(intermediate)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you were pretty close with the idea of a recursion:

```
 def mycomputation(num, instruction_set):
     return num if not instruction_set else mycomputation(instruction_dict[instruction_set[0]](num), instruction_set[1:])
```

But why not decode the instruction set outside of the function and pass in the initial object plus the list of transformations? It can turn into a one-liner:

```
my_comp = lambda ini, funs: ini if not funs else my_comp(funs[0](ini), funs[1:])

print(my_comp("Hello, World", [
    lambda x: f"<h1>{x}</h1>", 
    lambda x: f"<body>{x}</body>", 
    lambda x: f"<html>{x}</html>",
])) # -> <html><body><h1>Hello, World</h1></body></html>
print(my_comp(2, [lambda x: x**2, lambda x: x+5, lambda x: x+7])) # -> 16
print(my_comp(2, [])) # -> 2 (noop)
```